# Best way to handle signUp and Edit Sign up Functionality

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on Android. I'm just trying to optimizing my code. Generally I have noticed so many issue which is optimize but due to some limited time we are not optimizing that. Here I have share my problem. basically in all application I have facing this same Issue.

**Problem**

What is the best way to handle signup Fragment and EditSignUp Fragment?

**Description**

Generally in my case I am making one single `registration.xml` and making two different Fragment `RegistrationFragment.java` and `EditRegistrationFragment.java`. Just like below.

RegistrationFragment.java

```
public class RagistrationFragment extends BaseFragment {

private TextView tvEmail;
private TextView tvLeaveIn;
private TextView tvUserName;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void inilialization()
{
    tvUserName=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
    tvLeaveIn=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvLeaveIn);
    tvEmail=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
}
```

EditRegistration.java

```
public class EditRagistrationFragment  extends BaseFragment {
private TextView tvEmail;
private TextView tvLeaveIn;
private TextView tvUserName;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void inilialization()
{
    tvUserName=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
    tvLeaveIn=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvLeaveIn);
    tvEmail=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    tvEmail.setEnabled(false);
}
```

So here code is not reused. It's just a Example.Here I have define one method for initializing UI but this method is not reused. I know you can reuse this kind of method putting in `BaseFragment` but it's not proper way because baseFragment will extend by all Fragment in `Application.initialization()` is just one example.

I hope you are clear with my problem

Please give me proper suggestion.

Thanks,